# Работа с инвентарем

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в игре есть инвентарь и реализован подбор предметов, соответственно с переносом в инвентарь.
Теперь мне нужно рандомизировать выпадение предметов при луте, условно, коробки.

Не могу разобраться, как мне обратиться к определенному предмету? Сейчас обращение работает так:

```
item[i] = hit.collider.GetComponent<Item>(); //то есть, предмет i = предмету, на который я навелся
```

Код инвентаря:

```
 List<Item> item;
public GameObject cellContainer;
public KeyCode showInventory;
public KeyCode takeButton;
void Start()
{
    item = new List<Item>();
    cellContainer.SetActive(false);
    for(int i = 0; i < cellContainer.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        item.Add(new Item());
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ToggleInventory();
    AddToInventory();
   

}

void AddToInventory()
{

    

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(takeButton))
    {
        Debug.Log("takeButton");
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000f))
        {
            Debug.Log("raycast");
            if (hit.collider.GetComponent<Item>())
            {

                Debug.Log("before the for");
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (item[i].id == 0)
                    {
                        
                        item[i] = hit.collider.GetComponent<Item>();
                        
                        

                        DisplayItems();
                       
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

 void ToggleInventory()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(showInventory))
    {
        if (cellContainer.activeSelf)
        {
            cellContainer.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            cellContainer.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}

public void DisplayItems()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
    {
        Transform cell = cellContainer.transform.GetChild(i);
        Transform icon = cell.GetChild(0);
        Image img = icon.GetComponent<Image>();
        if (item[i].id != 0)
        {
            
            img.enabled = true;
            img.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(item[i].pathIcon);

        }
        else
        {
            img.enabled = false;
            img.sprite = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Код item'a :

```
public string nameItem;
public int id;
public int amountItem;
public bool isStackable;
[Multiline(5)]
public string descriptionItem;
public string pathIcon;
public string pathPrefab;
```

Item я применяю к новому объекту на карте. Я пробовал забить List предметами от руки и использовать их, но ничего так и не вышло, предметы не отображались, где-то вылазили null'ы, и тд.

01.07.2020  Окей, попробовал сегодня создать еще раз список предметов вручную и рандомно вывести один из этих предметов в инвентарь, делал так:

```
int rand = Random.Range(1, 5);
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
        {
            if (item[i].id == 0)
            {

                item[i] = item[rand];



                DisplayItems();

                break;
            }

        }
```

Ошибка возникает в displayitems, пишет что "Transform child out of bounds" в строчке
"`Transform cell = cellContainer.transform.GetChild(i);`" (DisplayItems).

Забивал список так:

```
 item = new List<Item>() {
        new Item {id = 3, nameItem = "груша", pathIcon = "icon/Hleb", pathPrefab = "Prefabs/Apple"},
        new Item {id = 4, nameItem = "вишня", pathIcon = "icon/apple", pathPrefab = "Prefabs/Apple"},
        new Item {id = 5, nameItem = "мандарин", pathIcon = "icon/Hleb", pathPrefab = "Prefabs/Apple"}
        };
```

На сцене соответственно таких предметов нет, а есть только в списке.

Опять же, стоит вопрос, как мне обратиться к объекту со скриптом item, в списке его нет, а на сцене есть.

Сейчас все работает так:
Я создаю объект на сцене, кидаю на него скрипт item, он, соответственно, становится предметом, я могу его подбирать при нажатии на кнопку, когда смотрю на него, но меня это не устраивает.

Немного почитал сейчас про эту ошибку, и мне кажется, что displayitems видит только те item'ы, которые находятся на сцене....

Comment: Я в игрострое понимаю от слова "ничего", но вы видели как в играх находятся комнаты со всеми предметами из игры? Вроде как это делается как раз для копирования оных (сужу по всяким Скайримам). А по поводу рандомного выпадения шмота - вроде как есть список предметов, падающий с конкретного моба или босса, где у каждого предмета есть шанс выпадения (сужу по WoW).

Comment: Я логику выпадения предметов понимаю. Я не знаю как найти предмет...  Даже если я создаю список предметов, то при работе с этим списком , displayitems не может отобразить предмет.

Comment: Я написал это к вашему "На сцене соответственно таких предметов нет, а есть только в списке". Ни по шарпу, ни по юнити, я, к сожалению, вам помочь не могу(

Comment: Да, окей, в любом случае спасибо

Comment: А, все, я понял о чем вы говорили, спасибо за наводку, буду сейчас работать с  этой темой)

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался. Создал базу данных всех объектов, которые есть -(Сделал платформу и выставил на нее все предметы) - после чего тянул все данные оттуда, и сейчас все работает как нужно. Спасибо всем за внимание!